# require comment or note when user changes cell value excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a spreadsheet where there are default discounts for different pieces of equipmemt.  Sometimes a change in discount is warranted.  But, the salesmen are notorious for changing the discount when it hasn't been authorized.  I'd like to require a comment if the default value is changed, or even just automatically open the cell comment window if the value is changed.  What code can I use to open the comment (or note) for user input from VBA?  Seems like it'd be easy, but I can't find it online.  Thanks!!

Comment: What column are the prices found?

Comment: Need to know where to limit the scope of the macro. You don't want to force a comment when they change any cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want the code to execute when a price is changed, you need to limit the scope of the `WorkSheet_Change` event. Ideally, your prices will span one column.

This code will only execute when a cell is changed on `Column E` - you will need to change this accordingly.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Change this line to modify scope of macro
If Target.Count <> 1 Or Target.Column <> 5 Then Exit Sub

    Dim Reason As String

    MsgBox "Changing the price requires a comment", vbCritical

    On Error Resume Next
        Reason = Application.InputBox("Please justify the price discount: ", "Discount", Type:=2)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Reason = "" Or Reason = "False" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            MsgBox "Unable to change price"
            Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        Target.ClearComments
        Target.AddComment Reason
    End If

End Sub
```